# Link to SQLite database created with Firefox

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I'm trying to start with SQLite and the Firefox add-on to create a new database. I don't really see how we call the database in the code, once the tables are created with Firefox.

I opened SQLite Manager in Firefox. Then I created all my tables. Now, how can I link them to my code with this, for example:

```
-(void) getQuestions:(sqlite3_stmt *)reqCompilee {        
    while(sqlite3_step(reqCompilee) == SQLITE_ROW) {        
        NSString * myTexte = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:    
                                (char*)sqlite3_column_text(reqCompilee, 1)];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get every thing [here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/) for implementing sqllite in your project.

in this tutorial you find other important links.

Comment: thanks, is it always needed to use the "terminal" ? or with any software manager it does that for you? i'll read the link , thank you very much

Comment: No need to use console you can enter values directly by open tables from firefox and also by coding. read some other tutorial of this sequence they shows max things. BY the way don't forget to accept the answer if you solves your problem or upvote can encourage any one to take interest in giving answers.